# R: How to name a column in a time series when the column name is NULL

Tags: r, time-series

This is my dataframe:

| year | month | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2008 | 2 | 16 |
| 2008 | 3 | 36 |

I convert it to a time series like this:

```
data <- ts(data$count, start = c(2008,2), frequency = 12)
```

In the time series, the column name 'count' gets changed to NULL:

```
> colnames(data)
NULL
```

and I can't change it using the 'usual' method `colnames(data) <- c("count")`, as I get an error that I'm trying to change the colnames for an object with less than 2 dimensions. It does NOT change the column name to NULL if I keep the column 'year', for example. But I don't need that one and would prefer to remove it. Deleting the column 'year' AFTER the transformation to a time series changes the column name of 'count' to NULL as well.

Any ideas? either on how to avoid the renaming to NULL or how to rename from NULL to any other name.

EDIT: I made the wrong assumption that a ts object usually has a column name. Because I did have another ts which did have a column. After fixing this, my time series are now all without colnames and all is good. Thanks.

Comment: A time-series object is not a data.frame. It does not have `colnames()` or `names()`. It just has dates and values. And you fill it with the values 16 and 36, beginning in February 2008.

Comment: @MartinWettstein thanks, I realize now my mistake was in another ts, which does have a column: Time-Series [1:194, 1]. I fixed this and now none of my ts have colnames anymore - which I previously assumed was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, what you are trying to do is to change the class of your column `count` to a time series. What you do in your syntax, however, is overwriting the object `data` with this one column. A `ts()` object does not have any columns and column names, it's just a special vector.

If you write:

```
data$count <- ts(data$count, start = c(2008,2), frequency = 12)
```

You just transform the column `count` to a time series. Your data does not change visibly, but the column is now a time-series:

```
> data
  Year Month count
1 2008   Feb    16
2 2008   Mar    36

> data$count
     Feb Mar
2008  16  36
```

Now, you can work with this one column and still have your data.

Comment: I was trying to overwrite the object data. That was on purpose. However, I was under the impression a ts does have column names, because I DO have another time series object which has a column: Time-Series [1:194, 1] instead of Time-Series [1:194]. After your answer I realized the mistake was in the other ts. I fixed this and now none of my ts have any colnames.